# Bundle deployment issue jboss fuse esb

Tags: maven, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb, camel-cxf

I am getting below error while deploying the module into fuse. Module deployment is failing. I am using processor to add custom soap headers. Maven install is happening properly.

```
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=xxyyzz-business; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.0.0,1.0.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve createProspect-business/1.0.0: missing requirement [createProspect-business/1.0.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.cxf.binding.soap)(version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))"]

    Code in processor class is
public class soapheader implements  Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange)throws Exception{
List<SoapHeader> soapHeaders = new ArrayList<SoapHeader>();
        String user = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><UsernameToken xmlns=\"http://siebel.com/webservices\">XYZ</UsernameToken>";
        SoapHeader soapHeader = new SoapHeader(new QName("http://siebel.com/webservices", "UsernameToken"), getSoapHeaderElement(user));
        soapHeader.setDirection(Header.Direction.DIRECTION_IN);
        soapHeaders.add(soapHeader); 


Dependency I am using in pom.xml along with other dependencies.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
</dependency>

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue.
```

Comment: Install the apache cxf features.

Comment: I resolved it by using the Embed-Dependency tag inside the configuration tag.